# Stack trace in running program (pstack equivalent in Windows)

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio

I'm trying to debug a .NET application that deadlocks/freezes at certain times. Is there a way to see what the application is doing when it freezes? I assume Visual Studio provides some way to see stack trace after attaching to an application? (I did try *Debug > Attach to process* and opened the *Call Stack* and *Stack Trace Explorer* Windows but nothing is shown there). I'm looking for something equivalent to what `pstack` (on Unix/Linux) does i.e. show stack of running process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After attaching Visual Studio to the process, just click Pause to see the Threads & Call Stack windows as-of any given time.